# Hibernate wrong table generated value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

Application is based on spring-boot and hibernate for JPA provider. Classes are mapped to use generated ID values from table. All classes looks similary to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    //...
}
```

Application builds schema (including hibernate_sequence table) using Flyway on boot, inserts base data and shift sequences in hibernate_sequence table, after that hibernate validate schema:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Problem is, that hibernate generates "random" values in tables.

```
SELECT * FROM users;

ID          NAME
1           user1
32899072    user2



SELECT * FROM HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES;

SEQUENCE_NAME   SEQUENCE_NEXT_HI_VALUE  
user            1000
```

Why hibernate generates this weird values ?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding @TableGenerator this table is created by hibernate for GenerationType.TABLE

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="Table_name")
@TableGenerator(
        name="Table_name",
        table="GENERATOR_TABLE",
        pkColumnName = "key",
        valueColumnName = "next",
        pkColumnValue="autoId",
        allocationSize=30
    )
private Long id;
```

Comment: annotation  @TableGenerator not resolved the problem.